# How can I use node.js to run a python file that runs forever?

Tags: python, node.js

I am wondering how to use node.js to run a python file that prints until it stops.

Right now when I run it it does not print anything, is there a way I can make it work properly?

Node.js

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')

var options = {
  pythonOptions: ['-u']
};

PythonShell.run('main.py', options, function (err, result){
      if (err) throw err;
      // result is an array consisting of messages collected
      //during execution of script.
      if (result !== null){
        console.log(result.toString());
      }
});
PythonShell.run('main.py', options, function (err, result){
      if (err) throw err;
      // result is an array consisting of messages collected
      //during execution of script.
      if (result !== null){
        console.log(result.toString());
      }
});
```

A function similar to mine

main.py

```
num = 1
while True:
    print(num)
    num += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `python-shell` package but you can easily spawn a new process to run python programs by using `spawn` method from `child_process` package that comes with node.

Here is how you can use it:

```js
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const cmd = spawn("python3", [__dirname + "/main.py"]);

cmd.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

cmd.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

cmd.on("close", (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Read the documentation for more info [[link](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options)]

Comment: I figured it out I was using something in python that broke that.